# Can't resolve the reference 'System.Object System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler... Anyone encounter the same error?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, system.configuration

I'm developing an application in Xamarin.IOS, after some updates I encountered the error below:

> Can't resolve the reference 'System.Object
>   System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler::Create(System.Object,System.Object,System.Xml.XmlNode)',
>   referenced from the method 'System.Object
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection::GetRuntimeObject()' in
>   'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

I tried deleting bin and obj folders, cleaning and rebuilding the solution. Mono versions on both PC and Mac are same and up to date.

Comment: Could you check what is your targeted .NET Framework version ?

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: Go to Project, then Properties

Comment: Target framework combobox in properties is empty, there is no item can be selected ):

Comment: What did you updated? Can you try to update the Xamarin.iOS version to latest?